# Compare Frequency & Recency of users with Goal Conversion using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

With google analytics is it possible to look at goal conversion rates for visitors with their frequency of visits?

So Id like to know the % of visitors that converted who only came to the site once, the % that came twice, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a custom report
2. Dimension, choose "Count of Visits"
3. Metric, choose "Goal Conversion rate"